# How to show current time in 24 hours format in Flutter, not using AM or PM?

Tags: flutter, dart

how can I show the time format in 24 hours in flutter, but not using AM or PM, like if there is afternoon 1 o'clock the how can i show is 13 hours ago. Please suggest me.

Comment: Have a look at this package - https://pub.dev/packages/timeago

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use `DateFormat` from [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) and use `HH` to show hours in 24-hours format:

```
var now = DateTime.now();
print(DateFormat('HH:mm:ss').format(now));
```

Result:

```
14:43:41
```